# Android Button Click issue

Tags: android, buttonclick

Hi I am having issues understanding why this doesn't work.  I have a button and when you click on it it doesn't go to the new activity.  I am trying to just have a simple button click that will go to another activity that has a fragment on top of it.

my code for the event click is as follows:

```
public class PlanMeMainFragment extends Fragment {

    private Button mNewButton, mExistingButton;

        mNewButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.new_event_button);
        mNewButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((PlanMeMainActivity) getActivity()).newActivityToLaunch(1);

            }
        });
        return  v;
    }
}
```

**my activity**

```
public class PlanMeMainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.planme_main_fragment);
    }

    public void newActivityToLaunch(int i) {
        Intent myIntent;
        switch(i){
        case 1: myIntent = new Intent(PlanMeMainActivity.this, NewEventSetupActivity.class);
        }

        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}
```

I listed the manifest as such:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.pctoolman.planme.app.PlanMeMainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name="com.pctoolman.planme.app.NewEventSetupActivity"
    android:label="@string/setup">
</activity>
```

Comment: What do you mean - "this doesn't work"? Does your app crash or nothing happens?

Comment: when i click on the button there is no response.  Even the logcat doesn't register anything happened.. The app doesn't crash.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something else, answer's @vdisawar gives me the idea:

**in your Fragment:**

```
// in your onClick method  
// call a method in your Activity 
((PlanMeMainActivity) getActivity()).newActivityToLaunch();
```

**in your FragmentActivity:**

```
// newActivityToLaunch method  
public void newActivityToLaunch() {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(PlanMeMainActivity.this, NewEventSetupActivity.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

With this tip, you will able to call different activities with the same method from different fragment, let see a simple example:

**FragmentA wants to launch Activity1:**

```
// call a method with an integer 
((MainActivity) getActivity()).newActivityToLaunch(1);
```

**in another fragment (FragmentB), this one wants to launch Activity2:**

```
// call the same method with another integer 
((MainActivity) getActivity()).newActivityToLaunch(2);
```

**then in your FragmentActivity, the method is:**

```
// newActivityToLaunch method  
public void newActivityToLaunch(int i) {
    // create a general intent
    Intent myIntent = null;
    // switch i received from fragments
    switch(i) {
        // received from FragmentA
        case 1: myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity1.class);
        // received from FragmentB
        case 2: myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
    }
    // start the activity
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: tried this still nothing happens, logcat as well doesnt register anything.  Thanks.

Comment: I did not use the android:onClick.  What do i set it as?

Comment: hi I followed your suggestions, can you see my edits I made and see if i am on the right track? Thanks?

Comment: Did you set newActivityToLaunch method **In the Activity** (because your edit suggests that's in your Fragment Class)? Another thing, this `myIntent== new Intent(PlanMeMainActivity.this, NewEventSetupActivity.class);` must to be `myIntent = new Intent(PlanMeMainActivity.this, NewEventSetupActivity.class);`! One = is necessary because you make a comparator instead. Did you test your new code?

Comment: my mistake I had it in the fragment instead of the activity.  I fixed it.  The only issue i have now is it complains about startActivity(myIntnent);  variable is not intitalized.  I will update the code above to show you what I have.  Thanks.

Comment: It's because I forgot to initialized `myIntent` (- I updated my answer). You have just to set this to null as `Intent myIntent = null;` and it works.

Comment: Thank you that fixed my button issue.  I think I am not calling the fragments correctly as i get an error that my fragments have never been used.  I will open a separate question if I can't figure this out.  Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help you with this. Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this :

```
<activity 
   android:name="com.pctoolman.planme.app.NewEventSetupActivity"
   android:label="@string/setup">
</activity>
```

to this:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.pctoolman.planme.app.NewEventSetupActivity"
    android:label="@string/setup">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: tried this still nothing happens, logcat as well doesnt register anything.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an interface in your Fragment class and implement that interface in the activity in which your fragment is inflated. That way when the button is clicked in your activity, the interface method will be called in the `onClick` method in your fragment and will execute the code of that interface method in your activity. In this case your method will launch an intent.

**Step 1:** create the interface within your fragment class

```
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    public void onFragmentInteraction();
}
```

**Step 2:** Create a variable for the interface in your fragment class

```
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
```

**Step 3:** Initialize the listener by overriding the onAttach method and making sure the listener is implemented in the fragments activity

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}
```

**Step 4:** Handle the onClick method in your fragment class

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.planme_main_fragment, container, false);

    mNewButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.new_event_button);
    mNewButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(); // executes this method in the activity
        }
    });
    return  v;
}
```

**Step 5:** Implement the interface in your activity

```
public MainActivity extends Activity implements 
          PlanMeMainFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener
```

Override the interface method in your activity

```
public void onFragmentInteraction(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewEventSetupActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

**Step 7:** detach the listener in your fragment class

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}
```

See the Android Training lesson  [Communicating with Other Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) for more information.